# Fetching data from URL works in ReactJS but does not work in Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Fetching data from URL by search it, it works in React and not working in React Native how to solve the problem?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, StatusBar, ScrollView, View, Text, TextInput, Button  } from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';


export default class Main extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      ifscCode:"",
      detail:{}
    }
  }

  ifscSearch = () => {
    const that = this;
    axios.get('https://ifsc.razorpay.com/${this.state.ifscCode}')
    .then(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 200){
        that.setState({detail:response.data})
        console.log(data);
    }    
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
  ifscCodeChange = (Value) => {
    this.setState({ifscCode:Value})
  }




render() {
    return (
        <>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.maincnt}>

                    <View style={styles.inpcnt}>
                        <NewIfsc ifscCodeChange={this.ifscCodeChange} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.btncnt}>
                        <Button title='Search' style={styles.btn} onClick={this.ifscSearch} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.listcnt}>
                        <Text>BANK: {this.state.detail.BANK}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.BRANCH}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.STATE}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.CONTACT}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.ADDRESS}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.BANKCODE}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.DISTRICT}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.STATE}</Text>
                        <Text>{this.state.detail.IFSC}</Text>

                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    )
}
}

class NewIfsc extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.inpcnt}>
                <TextInput style={styles.txtinp} maxLength={11} placeholder='ifsc code search' onChange={(e)=>this.props.ifscCodeChange(e.target.Value)} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    maincnt:{
        flex:1,
        margin: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    inpcnt:{
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    btncnt:{
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    listcnt:{
        marginTop: 20
    },
    txtinp:{
        width: 350,
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 25,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'indigo',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        padding: 10
    },
    btn:{
        width: 100,
        height: 70,
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    listcnt:{
        marginTop: 50,
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }

  });
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what errors you are seeing when you attempt to debug.